# RegEx Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, expression, notepad++

I have series of line in following format:

```
               LINE:  5190 STNO:  22669  SI: VOICE
          CCT   LINE    STNO  SI    BUS TYPE
          003   6269                OPTI ONLY     
           MULTLINE 8. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
           001 SUBUNIT . . . . . DIGITE MAIN      DEFIL/TRS
           (ALT_ROUT: N)       (OPTIIP  )
               LINE:  5291 STNO:  29956  SI: VOICE
```

What I need to find through regex (notepad++) are the numbers just after "STNO:"

There are approximately 100 of such matches.

I tired STNO:\s+\d{4,5} but it is taking STNO also into the match which i do not want. Please help.

I need to keep the matched result only and rest i want to delete or copy the matched items to a new file whichever is easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a two step approach. First get all the lines with the STNO and a number. Second remove everything except the number.

Select the **Mark** tab in the find dialogue. Ensure **Bookmark line** is ticked. In the **Find what** box enter `STNO:\s*\d+` and then click **Mark all**.

Access Menu => Search => Bookmark => Copy bookmarked lines. Then paste into another buffer. Alternatively, to work in the same file use Menu => Search => Bookmark => Remove unmarked lines. Now you should have all the wanted lines in a buffer.

Do a regular expression search and replace setting **Find what** to be `^.*STNO:\s*(\d+).*$` and **Replace with** to `\1`. Then click **Replace all**.

The above assumes that there is only one number to be found per line.

=========================

As only the numbers are wanted, another method would be to put line breaks plus a marker around the wanted numbers, then delete any lines without the marker, finally delete the markers.

Let the marker be `keep`. Do a search and replace setting **Find what** to be `keep` and **Replace with** to a single space character, make sure **Match case** is not selected; then click **Replace all**. Next, do a regular expression search and replace setting **Find what** to be `^STNO:\s*(\d+)` and **Replace with** to `\r\nkeep\1\r\n`. You might want **Match case** ticked; then click **Replace all**. Next do a mark lines (as described above) with **Find what** set to `keep`, followed by Menu => Search => Bookmark => Remove unmarked lines. Finally, do a search and replace setting **Find what** to be `keep` and **Replace with** to be empty.